# Can't click a button on a pop-up in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide, popup

I am trying to click a button on a pop-up which is opened from another pop up in Selenium IDE. I have no problem running commands in the second pop i.e. I can search for and select awards however when I try to click the Add button nothing happens. If the step is recorded in IDE the following commands are displayed:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//button[@type='button']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_New_pickerComponents_ButtonAddToTableResults</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

but this doesn't work. I have also tried:

```
 <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>xpath=//span[text()='Add']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
**<span class="ui-button-text">Add</span>**
</button>
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
```

but no joy. I'm not sure why I can use other commands in this pop-up and not be able to click the add button.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no any support in Selenium IDE for multiple windows. Try using selenium WebDriver instead if you have possibility

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:
ClickAndWait  css=button:contains("Add")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command in your script this will work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add'")).click;
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had issues where I'd click a link, opening a pop up, and Selenium IDE could not find the element within the pop up. The way I was able to solve this issue, was have the "Implicit Wait" plugin installed. Instead of a "click" on a link, I did a right click and selected "open in new tab" which removed the issue of the pop up and everything worked perfect for me.